Freeform search function not working on iPadOS 18.0?
When searching Freeform boards on iPad, the iPad User Guide (iPadOS 18) states that:

Search all boards: Tap the search bar in the top-right corner of the All Boards screen. Any board that contains the text appears in the search results.

Does this function work for anyone? For me, when I search all boards via the search bar it is only searching titles, not any text within my boards.
